# How to make `onResume` only be called when the activity comes to screen and not by other methods calling it

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, permission-denied

I have a situation with `onResume()` method and I don't know how to solve it.
conssider the following code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        Log.d("tag", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //do something only when everytime the activity comes to screen
        Log.d("tag", "onResume");
    }

    private void myMethod() {
        this.onResume();
    }
}
```

If we asume that `myMethod` will definitly be called, I don't want to let onResume() to execute `//do something only when everytime the activity comes to screen`. I should note that `myMethod` is a fixed method and cannot be changed.

PS:The reason that I am asking this question is that I have a simillar situation with PermissionDispatcher library with android 6 and I want to call a "risky permission" in the `onReume()` method but if the user denies the permission, it will call the `onReume()` again, and since the permission required task is in the `onResume()`, the permission will be denied again and cauases an inifite loop

could anyone give me a suggestion?

UPDATE: here is the [permissionDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) library and the [issue](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/issues/90) that is related to my problem

Comment: You shouldn't call the `onResume` method. Those callbacks are supposed to be called by the system.
You should move the logic you want to execute in `onResume` in a separate method.

Comment: I dont call it. There is a method on android system permission manager itself that calls it

Comment: You should post your actual code then. Btw, I don't think the library calls onResume .. probably something is shown to the user and the ativity is paused and then resumed when the user is brought back to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

verify this method Already Executed or not simply in if Condition

```
Bool a=true;

     @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                //do something only when everytime the activity comes to screen
                if(a==true)
                   {
                   //your Actions 
                    }
        else if(a==false)
        {
        //do nothing 
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharedPreferences** in onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean firstStart = settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
   if(firstStart) {
    //do something only when everytime the activity comes to screen
    Log.d("tag", "onResume");
    //display your Message here
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
     editor.commit();
   }

}
```